# Lotus Notes 9: Box appeared between Subject and Mail Body

Tags: lotus-notes

Lotus Notes suddenly shows the box highlighted in red in the picture below for a colleague of mine in the new mail window. This box first appeared when she ran a VBA macro that automatically creates draft emails, but neither was I able to find any line of code that looks like the cause of this nor did the same box show up for me when I ran the macro.

Does anyone know what this box is called and how I can turn it off again?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqQWt.png)

Thanks!

Comment: If that appears when you just do a Create->Memo, then it's probably in the form design.  It looks like an embedded view.  I'd look at the Memo form in designer and see if it shows up there.

Comment: Its the Conversation- View. Just disable with Action bar: Show -> Conversation

Comment: Unfortunately neither of these suggestions solved my problem. I'm not able to find the option to hide/unhide this box...